# Flowgear Web Request

Tags: flowgear

I have issue in send json data usingi web request node to,I have used web request node to send request on specific web service URL(created web service in java) and in web service received json data pass by web request post data but in web service post data are not received.I have successfully done invoked flowgear specific workflow endpoint via web request URL and pass static json data into post data property in web request node it is work and store data into database.

```
URL->http://...
Header-> I have not set any header(I have test set contenttype header but same issue is occur)
ContentType->application_json
Method->POST
Post data->{"Account":"1","Name":"testingaccount","Contact_Person":"abc","Telephone":"12345"} 
ResponseBody->Column \u0027test_customer_name\u0027 cannot be null
```

Please help me what is missing in web request node configuration?

Comment: Could you share your workflow so I can see how the web request has been set up? If you have sensitive information in it, copy the workflow, remove the sensitive information in the copied workflow and then share that.

Comment: http://flowgear.me/s/Y83VyXx

Comment: That looks right. Are you sure you're not getting a post body? the response you have there is an error on a field called test_customer_name which wasn't in the request JSON. The only other possibility I can think of is the content encoding. Try setting content type to none and then add the header "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"

Comment: I have try set header Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 but same error.if any other header is required or any userAgent is set?

Comment: test_customer_name it is my database table field set "Name":"value" to this field and same as other

Comment: I have append query string like below it is successfully get this data 
http://...?Account=1&Name=testingaccount&Contact_Person=abc&Telephone=12345"

Comment: Your web request definitely looks correct, perhaps trying POSTing something to it on a server you have control over so you can confirm whether the POST payload is being transmitted.